# Unable to run Woden Physics Example in Pharo

Tags: c++, swig, smalltalk, pharo, bullet

I am trying to run the Woden Physics Example inside Pharo which involves getting Bullet properly compiled and the smalltalk bindings properly installed in Pharo.

I am using Linux Mint 17 x64.

But NativeBoost seems unable to load the compiled libraries. I have been using the sources provided here:

https://github.com/ronsaldo/bullet-pharo

https://github.com/ronsaldo/swig

I built the modified version of swig as well as the bullet libraries and bindings with the provided build scripts. 
I also have doublechecked that the bullet libraries are 32 bit.
Opening up the Woden physics example returns this error:

```
 failed to get a symbol address:
 PharoNB_new_BTDefaultCollisionConfiguration__SWIG_1
```

When examining the call stack in the debugger, it turns out that the module handle is 0.

I verified this by executing the same message as

```
BulletCInterface nbLibraryNameOrHandle
```

executes:

```
NativeBoost forCurrentPlatform loadModule: 'BulletPharo'
```

This message returns 0. I tried to specify the full path to libPharoBullet.so in the workspace, like:

```
NativeBoost forCurrentPlatform loadModule: 
'/home/martin/.local/share/Pharo/bullet-pharo/libBulletPharo.so'
```

with the same result. I also verified it with a 32 bit system library of mine (liblzma) and there NativeBoost was able to load it, as it returned a non-zero handle.

So i suspect something during compilation went wrong...
I also did

```
readelf -h libPharoBullet.so
```

and its ABI was "UNIX - GNU" while the ABI of pharo-vm is "UNIX - System V"

Could this be the problem here ?
How can i force the ABI to be System V when compiling ? I use gcc 4.8.2

Or what steps could i otherwise perform ?